# Redis slower than MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, redis

I have two methods one of them queries the database and another one retrieves data from Redis cache.

```
public function aaa()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
        $gl = DB::connection('webhesab')->table('gl_trans')
            ->where('memo_', 'LIKE', '%شعبه%')
            ->orWhere('account', '=', 111001)
            ->where('dimension2_id', '<>', 1)
            ->orWhere('person_id', '=', 0)
            ->where('dimension2_id', '<>', 1)
            ->orWhere('type_no', '<>', 50)
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();
    }
}

public function bbb()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {

        $gl = cache()->get('gl_trans');
    }
}
```

value of the cached object is exactly like query value.

But cache is so much slower than database query. roughly `aaa` longs 300 ms and `bbb` longs 1900 ms.
Why? What is the problem?

Comment: maybe because inside your for loop of bbb you get all the data each time ?

Comment: why you use for loop in cache?

Comment: no only 10 records just like aaa

Comment: I want to test it and have a benchmark

Comment: Sorry but we need more information about your redis cache configuration because a simple line of code like that does not provide anything usefull

Comment: What kind of configurations?

Comment: You should also check if it is the connection or the fetching (or both) that's slow. What does the function `cache()` contain? Are you reusing the connection on each iteration or are you creating new connections?

Answer (score 0):

you should post cache() implementation. without those, people can't help you explain why it's slow

there are some other points

1. redis shouldn't be that long even if you're not using pipeline or mget
2. you can use pipeline or mget to speed up redis even further.